# Trouble Factory Resetting Hololens 2

Tags: hololens

I received a Hololens 2 that was previously used by someone else. Their account is currently signed in so I have been trying to factory reset it following this guide provided by Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-recovery#clean-reflash-the-device). However, when I trying to follow the "Clean-Reflash" section it requires me to be signed in to perform the reset. This results in a chicken or the egg problem as I don't have access to the signed in account, but I am unable to reset the device to log into a new one. Are there any other reset options?

[Permission denied when trying to reinstall software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e72oG.png)

Comment: For this device issue, it is recommended to open a support ticket through this link: http://aka.ms/hololenssupport for a one-to-one support service..

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. You need to do a manual installation instead of a normal one as in the documentation.